# How to determine classsNN of a control by its color or by its location in autohotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

Friends I want to retrieve the text from a control using controlgettext command. I tried to use classNN of the specific control to retrieve its text but the classNN keeps changing so it caused problem. So I automated the mouse pointer to go to the specific control to retrieve its classNN. I also tried to use ahk_id of the specific control to retrieve its text but it has the same problem also i.e. it also keeps on changing. So I want a way to directly retrieve the classNN from the color of the specific control. My codes are these

```
PixelSearch, Px, Py, 131, 302, 214, 316, 0xCEFFCE, 3, Fast RGB  
;first it searches the color of the control in the given coordinates on the  screen
 sleep 100
 mousemove %Px%, %Py%  ;then the mouse pointer moves to that control
 sleep 100
 MouseGetPos, X, Y, WIN, CONTROL ;then classNN is retrieved by Mousegetpos  command
 sleep 100
 ControlGetText, OutputVar, %CONTROL%, Finacle - Microsoft Internet Explorer
 ;then text is retrieved from controlgettext command using classNN
 sleep 100
 msgbox the text of the control is %OutputVar%
```

So kindly tell me is there any way to retrieve classNN of the specific control by its color? I do not want to move the mouse pointer to the specific control first and then to retrieve its classNN. I want any direct way to retrieve classNN of the specific control by its color or by its location on the screen.  As There are so many controls on the screen and their classNN keeps changing. Only two things do not change first is its location on screen and second is its color. so can't we retrieve the classNN of the control by its location or color? as `PixelSearch, Px, Py, 131, 302, 214, 316, 0xCEFFCE, 3, Fast RGB` now if there is any control under the coordinates %Px% and %Py% , then its classNN should be retrieved (without moving the mouse pointer to these coordinates). Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Just use [AutoIt 3 Window Spy](http://i.imgur.com/HfPIOdO.png) it gives you all of the information you'll need. The link is a picture of what the program shows.

Comment: Dear @DrZoo I am already using window spy tool for determining classNN and other things about a control. Parhaps you did not understand my question. I simply want a way to determine the classNN or ahk_id of a control from its color or coordinates on the screen. Please help